# How to remove the second column of a .txt file?

Tags: cut

I am working on a .txt file which is the output of a neuroscience program called fsl.
It does have 2 column and I want to remove the second one, I test some of the suggested codes but it seems like the Linux commands couldn't separate the two columns.
Any idea how to discard the second column?
For example, I tried `cut -f1,1 num.txt` but it doesn't work.

```
0 0.000000 

49 1435.537231 

11 322.263489 

0 0.000000 

0 0.000000

0 0.000000

0 0.000000 

360 10546.804688 

83 2431.624512

0 0.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a space-delimited file.

To extract the first column to a new file:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 1 data >data.new
```

The `-d ' '` tells `cut` to use a space as the delimiter. The default is to use a tab character.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is a powerfull tool IMO worth learning the basics at least. There are many tutorials. To unconditionally print the first column, all you need is:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt
```

The advantage over `cut` is that it will consider any blank character as the separator (though with some implementations, it's limited to the SPC and TAB characters only), will ignore leading and trailing ones and consider sequences of one ore more blanks as *one* separator.

Comment: To @StephaneChazelas: Your edits are better than my brief answer originally was. Thank you for kindly enhancing it.